# Hadoop Credentials using jceks Password File

Tags: hadoop

while creating hadoop credential using :

```
hadoop credential create mysql.password -provider jceks://file/home/mahadev.duary/credential.jceks
```

it showing the following error :

```
[mahadev.duary@ip-10-0-20-183 ~]$  hadoop credential create mysql.banking.password -provider jceks://home/mahadev.duary/credential.jceks
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "home"
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3273)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3293)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3344)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3312)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:478)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.JavaKeyStoreProvider.initFileSystem(JavaKeyStoreProvider.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.AbstractJavaKeyStoreProvider.<init>(AbstractJavaKeyStoreProvider.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.JavaKeyStoreProvider.<init>(JavaKeyStoreProvider.java:49)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.JavaKeyStoreProvider.<init>(JavaKeyStoreProvider.java:41)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.JavaKeyStoreProvider$Factory.createProvider(JavaKeyStoreProvider.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.CredentialProviderFactory.getProviders(CredentialProviderFactory.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.CredentialShell$Command.getCredentialProvider(CredentialShell.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.CredentialShell$CreateCommand.validate(CredentialShell.java:357)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.CredentialShell.run(CredentialShell.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.CredentialShell.main(CredentialShell.java:472)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sWTa.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBJKO.png

Comment: Please don't use images for errors. Copy the whole text to your question

Answer (score 0):

The end of your error suggests you've not configured a provider in your core-site.xml. Please refer documentation on configuration - https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CredentialProviderAPI.html

If you want to configure some hadoop client like Spark or Sqoop, then you should place your credential file in a shared location like S3, then you can use path like `jcecks://s3@`, per the documentation, otherwise it's looking for that same file path on every YARN node, not just your local one